# PHP/jQuery Country/State form field selected

Tags: jquery

I've written an address form that uses an API to pull in countries to a select input, and then jQuery/ajax populates the related states/regions to another select input. This works fine except when some countries don't have a state/region to use (Åland Islands). In those cases I'm forced to include an "other-state" field, so I replace it with a text input.

My problem is when I choose different countries; if I choose one that doesn't have a state/region, it switches to text input, but won't switch back once I've selected another country.

jQuery:

```
$("#inputCountry").on('change', function () {
    $.getJSON("ajax/changecountry?country=" + $(this).val(), function (data) {
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        var string = '';
        $.each(data, function (i, o) {
            string += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
        });
        if (string !== '') {
            $('#inputState').html(string);
        } else {
            $('#inputState').replaceWith('<input id="inputOtherstate" placeholder="State or Region" type="text" class="form-control" name="other-state" />');
        }
    })
    .then(function () {
        $('#inputState').val($('#userstate').val()); 
    });
}).change();
```

---

Fields:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="inputCountry" class="form-label">Country</label>
    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Address Country" id="inputCountry" name="country">
        <?php
         foreach ($countries as $name => $code) {
            echo ($code==='US') ? '<option value="' . $code . '" selected>' . $name . '</option>' : '<option value="' . $code . '">' . $name . '</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="inputState" class="form-label">State</label>
    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" id="inputState" name="state">
        <option selected>Select a country...</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" id="userstate" value="<?= isset($user['state']) ? $user['state'] : '' ?>" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You replace the `<select>` with an `<input>`, but nowhere do you ever replace the `<input>` with a `<select>`.  I imagine you could do that in the `if` block of your condition:

```
if (string !== '') {
    $('#inputState').replaceWith('<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" id="inputState" name="state">' + string + '</select>');
} else {
    $('#inputState').replaceWith('<input id="inputOtherstate" placeholder="State or Region" type="text" class="form-control" name="other-state" />');
}
```

Another alternative could be to always have both form elements exist but have one hidden.  Then you can just `.show()` and `.hide()` then form elements as needed instead of replacing them entirely.  This would be particularly useful if you ever attach event handlers to them, since replacing them would get rid of those event handlers.